# Forming the alphabet of a grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

What does {nA|A->x element of P} mean when defining an alphabet ? Note that A is subscript

Comment: Is that $\{n_A:A\to x\in P\}$? Even if it is, we need more context in order to know what $n_A$ means.

Comment: A ∈ N where N is a non-terminal. I am not sure if it is possible to have non-terminals in the alphabet

Comment: I understood that $A$ is a non-terminal, and yes, the non-terminals are part of the overall alphabet of the grammar, in the sense that they can appear in words generated during production of terminal words. What I don’t know is the meaning of the notation $n_A$.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what is the meaning of nA maybe it is referring to the number of A's.